# CentOS 6.6, Limits of user-specific environment

Tags: linux, centos, permissions

So I'll add context, but my BLUF is this:

In an organization that actively prefers "old, known, stable" (CentOS 6.6, highly curated Repo, etc...) to "modern, efficient, effective", but allows me substantial latitude inside my own profile, how far can I (or should I) go in creating my own environment inside my profile, and what's the most sensible approach to making that happen?

An easy example of what I'm talking about is Python.  System wide I'm limited to 2.6, but no one cares if I run 2.7 or 3.4 for my own purposes, but even building them manually (never mind using tools like pyenv, etc) hasn't been successful (though it always seems *just* outside the reach of my skillset)

So no one has a problem with me compiling new code, or running packages from sensible sources.  Nothing I'm doing will be running in a SU context, etc, but I seem to be spending incredible amounts of time spinning my wheels here.  I can't install RPMs because I can't even run the damn tools (even in a user context), etc...  I imagine there's a way for them to fix the permissions to allow me to do that (without permitting me to make system wide changes), but before I go asking for stuff like that, I need to know that it's the best (or at least a viable) solution to my problem.

What route should I take to try and make this happen?  And beyond what I *can* do, I actually *DO* want to obey the general intent of these policies, so I'd like to avoid doing anything that really does introduce any security implications, so are there limits to how far I should take this?

Is using the package manager at all viable?  Building a functional build environment?  etc.

And of course, if there's a primer out there somewhere I should be reading, a link would be greatly appreciated.  My google-fu has failed me here (probably because I have a hard time succinctly describing the problem).

Comment: You could ask the sysadmins to install the appropriate [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/).

Comment: This VM is being made available to my group on a semi-informal basis.  More of a "nice to have favor" than a strong requirement.  Certainly if the requirements were more stringent I could push for things, but it just doesn't call for that (IMO).

Honestly, this is mostly a function of me trying to keep this as low-impact on them as possible, hoping that when I *NEED* something, I have as little resistance as possible :).  Could be totally unnecessary, but it's the way I like to operate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is what I got from your question. You want to have an environment that would contain any of versions of any of the packages that you feel are required correct? Should that be the case, you have no issues doing that since Linux actually supports that. There is few limits as to what you cannot do as your user.

For your first example, python. Sys admin refrain(explicitly) from upgrading this because it is very very essential for YUM and breaking it will leave the server non-updateable. This however does not stop you from creating sub folders in your home directory and bringing in an tar ball which has the required binaries. Just go here [Python Download](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) and pick a tar ball. Unzip it in your home and add a `export PATH=/location_to_bin_folder_for python:$PATH` in your .bashrc and you are good to go.

This is completely acceptable in the world of Linux(companies could have restrictions on what you install) and tar balls are generally the way to go for closed infrastructures. Package managers are generally something that are used by Admins and you would not be privy to that unless you have something specific in mind like a php version that comes from Red Hat or other 3rd party repo providers.

So as a summary, you are limited by the rules set by your admins. In closed infrastructures, security is not really a big problem. You can take it a step further and make RPMs if you needed to with tar balls as updates and you can subscribe to updates to keep the RPM updated. I would find out how much they would want to limit you but practically all dev tools are available as tar archives for this purpose.

EDIT :

The easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is the way alternatives is done. You can do that bu creating a folder in your home like
`/home/user/bin`

Install python and something else, like say Java in two seperate folders

`/home/user/python` and `/home/user/java.`

In your bin folder, create symlinks to the desired binaries

`$ ls -l /home/user/bin`

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 13 May 19 19:59 java -> /home/user/java/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 13 May 19 19:59 javac -> /home/user/java/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 15 May 19 19:59 python -> /home/user/python/bin/python
```

Add this to your .bashrc

```
export PATH=/home/user/bin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal session and try
`which python`

It should say `/home/user/bin/python`

Add any additional binaries you see fit with the versions of your choice and it will work as expected

Comment: So I've actually ran into some problems trying to build python (and several other packages).  Is there a succinct "make sure all these environment variables are set like this" sort of way to make sure that the make scripts (etc...) install things into (and later reference) the right folders?  That seems to be the thing killing me the most.